# A problem named out of memory in MS excel macro. As this occurs only in some PCs

Tags: excel, vba, stock

The macro code(using selenium basic) is basically stock data stacking program that collects data from DSE: Dhaka Stock Exchange using `xPathonUrl` function() in excel macro and then show the real time data (paid up capital, Ownership data : Period, Sponsor/Director(%),Government(%),Institute(%),Foreign(%), Public(%)) in the excel sheet.

[image]

Problem is, it performs perfectly in my PC and some of my friends' too, but not in the seniors' PC for whom I basically build the project to retrieve real time stock data.
The code is:

```
Sub PaidupCapital()
   Dim autobot As New WebDriver, By As New By
   autobot.AddArgument "--headless"
   lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
   
   autobot.Start "chrome"
   autobot.Wait (3300)

   For i = 5 To lastrow
       autobot.Wait (3300)
       link = Sheets(2).Range("a" & i).Value
       autobot.ExecuteScript "window.open(arguments[0])", link
       autobot.SwitchToNextWindow
       autobot.Wait (3300)        
   
       If autobot.IsElementPresent(By.XPath("//*[@id='consent-page']/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/button")) Then
           autobot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='consent-page']/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/button").Click
       End If
       
       paidcapital = autobot.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/section/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]").Text            
       Sheets(2).Range("I" & i).Value = paidcapital        
       foreign = autobot.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/section/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[11]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]").Text            
       Sheets(2).Range("Y" & i).Value = foreign        
       pub = autobot.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/section/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[11]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]").Text            
       Sheets(2).Range("Z" & i).Value = pub        
       institute = autobot.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/section/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[11]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]").Text            
       Sheets(2).Range("X" & i).Value = institute        
       govt = autobot.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/section/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[11]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]").Text            
       Sheets(2).Range("W" & i).Value = govt        
       director = autobot.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/section/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[11]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]").Text            
       Sheets(2).Range("V" & i).Value = director        
       Period = autobot.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/section/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[11]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]").Text            
       Sheets(2).Range("U" & i).Value = Period
   Next i
   
   MsgBox "Congratulations! Data has beed updated :)"    
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you print a screenshot of the error you are getting? With an uncomplete code and just your description it is difficult to help you.

Comment: What other software is the problem pc running? Reboot it and only run the minimum software to complete that task. Is the error still there?